# Matrix in a table

Tags: tables, matrices

I am trying to insert a matrix inside a table, and I am looking for a good way to do this. I attach my tex following. my problem is how can I insert caption ?

```
\begin{tabular}{|*3{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{.3\textwidth}|}}  
    \hline
    \textbf{$\chi_1=1.167$} & \textbf{$\chi_2=1.305$}&\textbf{$\chi_3=1.279$}\\
    \hline
    \[L_{0} = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc} -0.228&  -0.273&   0.934\\ -0.335&   0.923 &   0.188\\0.914 &  0.270 &   0.302 \end{array}\right]\] &   \[L_{0} = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc} -0.236&  -0.284 &  0.929\\-0.391 &  0.903&   0.176\\0.889  &0.321&   0.324 \end{array}\right]\]&    \[L_{0} = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc} -0.236&   0.284&   0.929\\-0.376&  -0.908&   0.182\\0.896& -0.306&   0.322 \end{array}\right]\]\\
        \noalign{\hrule height 1pt}
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) on this site you are much much more likely to get help if you provide a full minimal example, instead of just a sniplet like this. Then others does not have to guess the rest of the document. (3) A caption belongs to floating objects, so you'll need to wrap your tabular in a table environment.

Comment: note that `\textbf` does not affect mathematics so `\textbf{$\chi_1=1.167$} ` is the same as `\$\chi_1=1.167$ ` perhaps you want `\boldmath $\chi_1=1.167$ `

Answer (score 2):

- your problem is solved by comments below questions, so this answer is more off-topic:

  - your table is quit wide, so i use the `geometry` package to enlarge text area
  - for matrix i sug˙gest to use `bmatrix` from the package `amsmath`

    ```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry} % <--- added
    \usepackage{amsmath}               % <--- added
    \usepackage{array}                 % <--- added

    \begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{|*3{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{.3\textwidth}|}}
    \hline
    $\chi_1=1.167$  & $\chi_2=1.305$ & $\chi_3=1.279$   \\
    \hline
    \[
    L_{0} = \begin{bmatrix}       % <--- changed
        -0.228 &  -0.273 &   0.934\\
        -0.335 &   0.923 &   0.188\\
         0.914 &   0.270 &   0.302
            \end{bmatrix}
    \] &
    \[
    L_{0} = \begin{bmatrix}    % <--- changed
    -0.236 &  -0.284 &   0.929\\
    -0.391 &   0.903 &   0.176\\
     0.889 &   0.321 &   0.324
            \end{bmatrix}
     \] &
     \[
    L_{0} = \begin{bmatrix}   % <--- changed
     -0.236 &  0.284 &  0.929\\
     -0.376 & -0.908 &  0.182\\
      0.896 & -0.306 &  0.322
             \end{bmatrix}
    \]
                            \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{document}
    ```

[image]